# Excel CommandBars / Controls in local languages

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Win-XP / Excel 2003 / VBA ....

I have the following piece of code to intercept all paste activities initiated by the user (main menu, context menu and control-V key) and send it to a Sub TrappedPaste()

```
....
Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Paste").OnAction = "TrappedPaste"
Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Paste Special...").OnAction = "TrappedPaste"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Paste").OnAction = "TrappedPaste"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Paste Special...").OnAction = "TrappedPaste"
Application.OnKey "^v", "TrappedPaste"
....
```

This code works fine. The miracle happened during worldwide rollout of the sheet, because "Edit" isn't "Edit" and "Paste" isn't "Paste" in German, French and all other languages between (A)leut and (Z)apotec :-O

Q:

1. Is there a way of achieving
   independence from the language of
   the Excel User Interface, i.e. is
   there a numeric aequivalent to the
   "Paste" argument which is the same
   in all national languages?
2. how can I find this number?
3. is ctrl-V always ctrl-v in all local Windows languages?

Thanks in advance for any help

Kind regards MikeD

Comment: You forgot the `Shift+Ins` and the right-click.

Comment: @GSerg: thanks for the hint on Shift-Ins .... right click opens the context menu which is addressed by ...CommandBars("Cell")....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each control on a toolbar has an `ID` which can be used with the `FindControl` function:

```
? application.CommandBars("Edit").FindControl(msoControlButton, 22).Caption
```

where `22` is the ID of the `Paste` button. As far as I was able to check, this number is the same accross different languages.
So you can look them up in the English version and just hardcode them.

Comment: OK I'll try that; and what about the command bar names, do they have similar ID's, because EDIT isn't EDIT in other languages as well

Comment: No, edit IS edit in other languages. Because, unlike the controls, the command bars have `.Name` and `.NameLocal`.

Comment: final solution based on your proposal is to replace ...Controls("Paste")... by ...FindControl(ID:=22)...  for paste and 755 for Paste Special. Will need to add one line for standard tool buttons as well - grrr - many thans for your help GSerg

Comment: In my experience you should also use the ID for the `CommandBars`. As GSerg said, the `Name` remains `"Edit"` in other languages. However, when multiple command bars have the same name (e.g. `"Cell"` command bar for Normal mode and Page Break Preview mode), you don't know which one you are going to get.